# Why was this valid answer diamond-moderator-deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-answers, specific-answer, moderators

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63313318/430766

The question asks for a problem involving numbers and this answer gives a valid solution, suggesting modulo instead of a loop. What's more, this is a new user, who is rightfully wondering why their answer was deleted. Flags haven't resulted in a reaction.

Since the deletion, two new answers were posted, both pretty much making a similar point than the deleted answer.

Comment: @TemaniAfif The question goes on to give a better approach, acknowledging that the OP's approach was correct, albeit slow. I see zero problem with that. If you stop reading after the first sentence, yes, this would be a non-answer.

Comment: What's achieved with deleting a correct answer, that could lead the OP onto the right track? Yes sure, the answers content is not quite explaining anything yet, but the correct action IMO here would be to recommend improving the description to the answerer instead of deleting and not giving any chance to improve.

Comment: @TemaniAfif then teach how to teach how to fish?

Comment: @JonasWilms answers arent generally mod deleted for being poor or even incorrect. There could be some other explanation or could be a mistake

Comment: Wrt *Flags haven't resulted in a reaction.* three hours is a really short time span for any reaction overruling a moderator's decision.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer in question was flagged as "not an answer" by a community member. To the moderator who originally handled this flag, the answer looked like it was thanking another answer and making a minor suggestion on how to improve it (*"your solution works fine. You can try the shorter…"*).

Upon closer inspection and review by other moderators, it was determined that this initial judgment was in error. When the answerer said "your solution", they were referring to the one proposed in the question. This was also the first answer that was posted to the question, so it's impossible that they could have been thanking and/or iterating on a previous answer.

For all of these reasons, the answer was undeleted and restored. Mistakes do occasionally happen when moderators handle not-an-answer flags, especially when they do so at high volumes and/or outside of their core subject-matter expertise. Neither is a reason to raise alarm; however, we do appreciate your bringing it to our attention when you disagree with one of our decisions. We're happy to review and reconsider.

As for *"Flags haven't resulted in a reaction"*: basically what [oguz ismail said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400125/why-was-this-valid-answer-diamond-moderator-deleted#comment788323_400125). The flag you had raised on the answer was only active for 1 hour before you posted this Meta question. The daily volume of flags on Stack Overflow is *vastly* higher than would allow us to guarantee sub-hour flag turnaround times. It wasn't a matter of us ignoring you or declining your flag; we just hadn't seen it yet.

But, for future reference, it is better to use Meta as a venue for questioning/disagreeing with a moderator's decision than to raise a second flag. Meta allows us to explain our rationale, something which cannot really be done in response to a flag. It also allows us to have a discussion and/or involve the larger community (including those with more relevant expertise), which can be very helpful in more complicated cases.

Comment: *it is better to use Meta as a venue for questioning/disagreeing with a moderator's decision than to raise a second flag* Are you sure? It's not all that uncommon to see something and think "I know how things work and that doesn't make any sense at all, did a mod press the wrong button, or fail to read closely enough?" in which case the fix from a custom flag is trivial and (I'd think) less stress-inducing than a public questioning of a simple mistake.

Comment: Of course, in other cases, if it *was* deliberate and might need more explanation than a sentence or two in the flag reply, or would benefit from community input, or might not require a mod to explain, I'd think *that'd* be the time to take things to Meta

Comment: @CertainPerformance If you want an explanation, then it needs to come to Meta. Only raise a flag if you're fine with the flag being simply and summarily declined. That said, there's nothing *wrong* with raising a flag if you think it was a genuine mistake and just want someone to take a second look at it. We *will* do that in response to a flag.

Comment: FWIW I undeleted based solely on the flags, and after talking with the moderator who deleted it. Cody is right in that if you want an explanation, flags are not the way to go. We can comment back on the flag, but it generates no notices and only the flagger can see it in their flags list.

Comment: Also, @Machavity, we have *extremely* tight character limits when we respond to flags. I can get may be one sentence there, if I work hard at compressing it. So it's not about the privacy or lack of notice, so much as whether you want more than 3 or 4 words.